# unfair synchronization among threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have a code pattern like this:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class TestRunner {
    public static final Object lockObject = new Object();

    public static final AtomicInteger counter1 = new AtomicInteger();
    public static final AtomicInteger counter2 = new AtomicInteger();

    public static class Runner1 implements Runnable {
        private volatile boolean running = true;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                synchronized (lockObject) {
                    counter1.getAndIncrement();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
                // Thread.yield();
            }
        }

        public void stop() {
            running = false;
        }
    }

    public static class Runner2 extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                synchronized (lockObject) {
                    counter2.getAndIncrement();
                }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runner1 runner1 = new Runner1();
        Runner2 runner2 = new Runner2();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(runner1);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(runner2, 0, 10);

        thread1.start();

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        timer.cancel();
        runner1.stop();

        int runner1Percent = (counter1.get()*100 /(counter1.get()+counter2.get()));
        System.out.println("No of times Runner1 got called: " + counter1.get());
        System.out.println("No of times Runner2 got called: " + counter2.get());
        System.out.println("Percentage Runner1 acquire the lock: " + runner1Percent);
        System.out.println("Percentage Runner2 acquire the lock: " + (100-runner1Percent));
    }
}
```

I run this code for about 10 second and here is the output:

```
No of times Runner1 got called: 877 
No of times Runner2 got called: 10 
Percentage Runner1 acquire the lock: 98 
Percentage Runner2 acquire the lock: 2
```

As indicated here, Thread1, is able to acquire the lock 98% while the timer, is only
able to acquire the lock 2%.

If I uncomment out the Thread.yield() statement and rerun it, the output
shows:

```
No of times Runner1 got called: 858
No of times Runner2 got called: 1001
Percentage Runner1 acquire the lock: 46
Percentage Runner2 acquire the lock: 54
```

This shows that Thread1 and Timer share the lock more uniformly. Does this mean the jvm has some optimization/caching so that Thread1 is able to keep acquiring the lock? If I am not able to replace the synchronized block due to some other restrictions, is Thread.yield() a right approach to have the threads sharing the lock more uniformly?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Native synchronization is [not guaranteed to be fair](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/starvation-and-fairness.html#synchronized). Try a `new ReentrantLock(true)` if you need fairness.

Comment: Runner1 is running in a tight loop: it exits the synchronized block and a few clock cycles later it tries to enter it again. Runner2 takes much more time: it is woken up when Runner1 exits from the synchronized block. But that doesn't mean that its running already: the OS needs to schedule that thread which takes more than just a few clock cycles and therefore the probability that Runner1 already acquired the lock again is high.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, I am extracting this pattern from some existing library codes, which I cannot change it to ReentrantLock.

Comment: yield is doing what it is supposed to here. api doc says it gives a hint to the scheduler. not sure what else there is to say about this.